# Save state of a container (LinearLayout)

Tags: android, android-fragments, containers, layout-inflater, savestate

I have two fragments.

In first fragment I have a container static (LinearLayout) that to the view of fragment. In this container i do a inflation of several views.

I change to a second fragment, but when i return to the first fragment the views inflated disappeared.

How I can save the state of the container? Someone can give me a example?
Thanks for yout help and attention

[image]

Comment: hi!,   plz post the code where you "change to a second fragment"

Comment: public InstantiatingTabListener(TabCompatActivity activity, Class cls){
  mActivity = activity;
  mClass = cls;
 }

 @Override
 public void onTabSelected(CompatTab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
  Fragment fragment = tab.getFragment();
  if(fragment==null){
   fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
   tab.setFragment(fragment);
   ft.add(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment, tab.getTag());
  }else{
   ft.attach(fragment);
  }  
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onCreateView is being called again upon returning and your fragment is being recreated.
One solution is to save your fragment state in onSaveInstanceState and reload it in onCreateView:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ..
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
       // reload state
    }
    ..
}

public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    // save dynamic state in outState
}
```

EDIT:

I've found this to work if you would like to keep the actual view:

```
private View mLayout;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (mLayout == null) {
      // this is the first time onCreateView has been called
      mLayout = inflater.inflate(..);
    } else {
      // remove previous parent
      ViewParent parent = mLayout.getParent();
      if (parent != null)
        ((ViewGroup) parent).removeView(mLayout);
    }
    return mLayout;
}
```

Comment: al thanks for yout reply. But, for example in onSaveInstanceState how can save the view that disappear for reload the same view in onCreateView function...? thanks for your help

Comment: in the outState bundle, you would put data to keep track of which dynamic layouts are currently displayed. eg. outState.putBoolean("showFragment", true); And then from reading savedInstanceState.getBoolean("showFragment"), you would be able to see what to readd.  I've edited my answer for if you want to retain the actual view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the saveinstance. The fragment save the state of the views that belongs to the fragment, but the other view that result of the inflations disappear.

I don't know how save the state (when change of fragment) inside a container, that change several times (dinamic)